# Unable to connect mongodb atlas to intellij MongoExplorer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, intellij-idea, mongodb-atlas

I'm using mongodb atlas for my backend and I'm trying to connect it to Mongo Explorer of intellij

This is the first image for furthur details

[image: I have replaced the <PASSWORD> with actual database password]

This is the second image where I provided the database username and password but still I'm not able to connect.

[image: Error image]

I have connected to localhost very easily without any problems but this is not connecting...

I'm using Intellij Idea Ultimate 2017.1.3 with student license. I think there is no problem with this particular license and Ide version

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check your server urls  field. Compare with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Yes it matched with the format specified it looks like this mongodb://practice:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-shj3q.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-shj3q.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-shj3q.mongodb.net:27017/<DATABASE>?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin

Comment: The given url format is mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

Comment: have you tried just `cluster0-shard-00-00-shj3q.mon‌​godb.net:27017, clust‌​er0-shard-00-01-shj3‌​q.mongodb.net:27017,‌​cluster0-shard-00-02‌​-shj3q.mongodb.net:2‌​7017` in the server url as mentioned below in the expected format ?

Comment: give me a second..I will try

Comment: no bro its not working

Comment: Its showing the same error

Comment: @bharath were you able to connect it?

Comment: @Andrey yes I'm successful connecting it. Just go through the comments. Since its a long time I forgot what I have actually done but definitely I have done something that was explained in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy steps:

1. Add these Dependencies in pom.xml file :

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. You want to add this code to application.properties file :

   ```
    spring.data.mongodb.uri= your_uri_here
    spring.data.mongodb.database= database_name_here
   ```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mine is a node project not a spring one.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@clust‌​er0-shard-00-01-shj3‌​q.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate why this is a solution to the question.